# Laravel - Validate quantity field on server side for product which have different quantities

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation, server-side

I have a form that has a drop-down to select a product from different product listings, upon selection an AJAX request is sent to fetch the quantity of that particular product and max attribute is set for the quantity HTML element.

> This is a form repeater (not any plugin) which creates a dynamic element on the fly when add new item is pressed and then another drop-down for product listing appears with its quantity HTML element (empty input element).

I am validating it on client-side by setting max attribute of quantity element, but how can I validate this on server-side for each product with respect to its quantity in the database.

If the user somehow opens developer tools in chrome and change the max attribute and submit the form my whole application will crash/create ambiguities.

I am using Laravel 5.7

This is how I am trying to achieve that.

```
$validated = $request->validate([
        'misc_equipment.*' => 'nullable|distinct',
        'misc_quantity.*' => 'required|numeric',
    ], [
        'misc_equipment.*.distinct' => 'This misc equipment has a duplicate value.'
    ]);
```

I just want to check that quantity from DB for that product

Comment: can't you get the qty from database and on submit compare it with input value coming from form and also show the code you have done so we can get proper idea what the problem is

Comment: well i can but its basically a form repeater that is creating confusion.

$validated = $request->validate([
            'misc_equipment.*' => 'nullable|distinct',
            'misc_quantity.*' => 'required|numeric',
        
        ], [
            'misc_equipment.*.distinct' => 'This misc equipment has a duplicate value.'
        ]);

I am trying to achieve that validation thing like that on misc_quantity, just like misc_equipment is checking for distinct. but its from database, hope you get my point. @pal

Comment: @pal validation code added

Comment: yaa i just check